# How to override an element's default style with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In CSS we can do:

```
div { font-size:20px }
```

To set the default font size for all `div`s. Is there a way to change default styles for elements with JavaScript?

Alternately, how could I find and set the above style rule? You can find classes by searching `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` by name, but I don't know how to find the style for `div`.

EDIT:

Oops, the answer is in my question.

My confusion arose from attempting to alter rules that were set for multiple elements at once.

So you *would* be able to find and alter the CSS rule for div as above.

What I don't know is how you'd alter the rule for multiple definitions:

```
div,span { font-size:20px }
```

You can't find the rule by searching for `div`, `span` or `div,span`.

Comment: *"but I don't know how to find the style for 'div'"* The same as you do with classes: You just find the rule whose `selectorText` property has the value `"div"`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that, thanks. Edited question for an additional case I haven't solved.

Comment: what a strange requirement, looks like you can't just access to your CSS file or simply your CSS is bad designed and you need JS to reset the `font-size` for all the `div` (by change the `font-size` in all possible rules which contain `div` selector). If you just need to override the `font-size` of all the divs, you can just ***add*** a new rule ***at the end*** so that it can override all the precedent defined style, of course it can just override `div` selector rule (following the CSS specificity rule).

Comment: Maybe the selector is normalized and you have to search for `div, size` instead. Or instead of testing the equality of the values, you test whether `div` is *contained* in the selector text. It might be easier though to simply add a new rule with a very high specificity.

Comment: It's for a full-window game where I'm resizing fonts based on window size. It works with styles, but I'd have to do less rule changing if I can set the default for div, input etc.

Comment: Ahh, it seems the selectorText is reformatted a bit. "div,span" becomes "div, span". Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pixelmike: Can't you simply set the `font-size` for all elements to `inherit`, e.g. `body * { font-size: inherit; }` (or `body div`) and then just change the font size of the body element via `document.body.style.fontSize = ...;` ? Or something similar? Seems it would be a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good suggestion as well, I will try some different approaches. Thanks again. (I'm ok with javascript and webgl but apparently my css is a bit lacking.)

Comment: If “the answer is in my question”, you should edit the question to make it clear *what the question was*, post an answer, and self-accept it. Changing the question is not constructive. If new questions emerge, post them as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to change the style of an determinated div you have to do this in you javascript code

```
getElementById('div_register').setAttribute("style","font-size:20px");
```

in this way you are getting de div by its id, and setting a style that you want, you can set differents styles with these and will save code space as declare one by one the style you want...i hope i helped you :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use style.fontSize property for setting font size using javascript. The code will look like

```
 document.getElementById("//id here").style.fontSize = "50px"; //size
```

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nP8Cd/)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of javascript you can change the DOM properties. You can create one outer div and give it some name/id. Then, loop through all inner divs and update the css style attributes.

```
     innerDivs = document.getElementById('odivID').getElementsByTagName('div');
     for (var i = innerDivs.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        innerDivs[i].style.fontSize = "25px";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by n number of ways, but I recommend to use class name:

**style**

```
div.my-style {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

**script**

```
...
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var len = divs.length;
var cn;
if(len --) do {
  cn = divs[len].className;
  if(cn) {
    cn += ' my-style';//<-- spaces to separate with the existing class names, if any
  } else {
    cn = 'my-style';
  }
  divs[len].className = cn;
} while(len --);
...
```

Note: Applying style to all divs will apply to those divs as well on the same page which you don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own css style rule that override the default one.

either

1. create `<style>` in `<header>` using javascript
2. or, link external css file `<link>`

please see fiddle using first method: http://jsfiddle.net/b8Hn7/

```
var myStyle = document.createElement("style");
myStyle.innerText = 'div { font-size: 40px; }';
document.head.appendChild(myStyle);
```

The above code overrides the default style by creating same rule but place after the default style, there is no need to "locate" the default style and change it.

Answer (score 0):

U can try it with create 'style' dom like my under code:

html:

```
</div>
```

js:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerText = 'div{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #c4e;}';
document.body.appendChild(style);
```